# Definition of a rim torus

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

We know a torus is $S^1 \times S^1 =T^2$.

We know a solid torus is $D^2 \times S^1$ whose boundary is a torus $S^1 \times S^1 =T^2$.

What is the definition of a rim torus?

Comment: Where did you heard of this term?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a new topological space; it's still a torus $T^2$. In the context of certain manifold surgery, called *rim surgery*, a particular torus merits investigation, and so the mathematicians who introduced the surgery ([Fintushel and Stern](http://faculty.sites.uci.edu/rstern/files/2011/03/42_Surfacesin4MfldsMRL.pdf)) called it the rim torus.